# How to pass a value from model to view in django?

Tags: python, django

## How to pass **codeval** variable from **models.py** to **views.py**:

in models.py

```
from django.db import models  
from django.contrib.auth.models import User  
from django.db.models.signals import post_save  
import random  
from django.core.mail import send_mail        

class UserProfile(models.Model):  
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)  
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')  
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')  
    website = models.URLField(default='')  
    mobile = models.IntegerField(default=0)  
    code = models.IntegerField(default=0)        

def create_profile(sender, **kwargs):  
    if kwargs['created']:  
    user_profile = UserProfile.objects.create(user=kwargs['instance'])  
    codeval = random.randint(111111,999999)    
    user_profile.code = codeval  
    user_profile.save()  
    receiver = User.objects.get(id=user_profile.user_id).email  
    send_mail(' Confirm your account on Abolombon',   
        'Thanks for signing up with Abolombon! Your Abolombon verification code is:\n %s\n\n Thank you\nAbolombon.com'%(codeval),   
        'testpurpose2040@gmail.com',   
        [receiver])

post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)
```

in views.py

```
def verification(request, args=codeval):
    return render(request,'website/verification.html',{'args':args})
```

I am making an e-commerce site in django where I need user registration option. For this purpose I am using django's build in user registration form. But I need to store some additional info about user like contact number, city etc. I also want to verify user sending a 6 digit code to their corresponding email address.

But in django's build in form their is no field to store verification code. So I have created UserProfile model to serve this purpose. And have created code field to store 6 digit random number.

I want to store this random number into code field and also send it to the user email address. And when user will enter the code a function will verify it with the stored one. For this I need **key** to retrieve the code from the db. So I want to pass this key to the **views.py**.

Thank you

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to get a `UserProfile` from a `codeval`?

Comment: I need UerProfile id to get UserProfile.objects.get(id=id).code to match it with user's one

Comment: On the page where the user enters the verification code, what other method do you use to verify their identity?  i.e. is it a custom URL for that specific user, or do they also enter their username or email address?  If so, then you can use that information to look up the user object and the UserProfile object.

Comment: def signUpView(request):

 if request.method == 'POST':
  form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
  form.is_active = False
  form.save()
  if form.is_valid():
   form.save()
   return redirect('/website/login/')
 else:
  form = RegistrationForm()
 return render(request,'website/signUp.html',{'form':form})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am interpreting your question correctly, you want `UserProfile.objects.get(code=codeval)`. This will give you the actual profile, so if you want the id, just do `UserProfile.objects.get(...).id`.

Note that your current code could give multiple profiles the same code, so you should either prevent that or get all profiles that match using `.filter` instead of `.get`.